# Warning: The object was not found using the test object description. Check the object's properties

Tags: hp-uft

I'm currently studying UFT. I encountered this: I have one object, which is a textbox field on my repository. I used that specific object twice on my script. The warning then occurs. "The object was not found using the test object description. Check the object's properties." May I know what to do so that warning will no longer occur?

Answer (score 0):

This warning means that UFT was not able to identify the object using the primary description it stored and that a fallback method called [Smart Identification](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_smart_identification.htm) was used.

This means that the identification properties that you're currently using (either Object Repository or descriptive programming) are out of sync with your web application and it's recommended that you update the description (perhaps by adding regular expressions).

The report should list which properties where used by Smart Identification and which were skipped), this may be a good starting point to choosing your description.